# Package won't start/stop in Synology DMS 7.0.1 when using synopkg

Tags: synology

I'm trying to start or stop a package in DMS 7.0.1 using the synopkg command, but while the command outputs that it was successful, refreshing the package manager still shows that the package is offline. Is there something I'm doing wrong or is there an alternative command I should be using? This is for PlexMediaServer, which I manually install.

```
$ /usr/syno/bin/synopkg start "PlexMediaServer"

{"action":"prepare","error":{"code":0},"stage":"prepare","success":true}
```

Listing installed packages:

```
$ /usr/syno/bin/synopkg list
...
PlexMediaServer-1.24.5.5173-7000: Plex organizes all of your personal media so you can easily access and enjoy it.
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If a user doesn't have permission to use the synopkg command, it will still execute and can show a successful status even if nothing happened. After checking the logs (/var/log/synopkg.log), nothing was even getting written.

Executing the commands with a `sudo` achieved the results I was looking for AND updated the logs.